# A fast solution to obtain the best ARIMA model in R (function `auto.arima`)

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, arima

I have a data series composed by 2775 elements:

```
mean(series)
[1] 21.24862
length(series)
[1] 2775
max(series)
[1] 81.22
min(series)
[1] 9.192
```

I would like to obtain the best ARIMA model by using function `auto.arima` of package `forecast`:

```
library(forecast)
fit=auto.arima(Netherlands,stepwise=F,approximation = F)
```

But I am having a big problem: RStudio is running for an hour and a half without results. (I developed an R code to perform these calculations, employed on a Windows machine equipped with a 2.80GHz Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU and 16.0 GB RAM.) I suspect that this is due to the length of time series. A solution could be the parallelization? (But I don't know how apply it).

Anyway, suggestions to speed this code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forecast package has many of its functions built with parallel processing in mind.  One of the arguments of the [auto.arima()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.7/topics/auto.arima) function is 'parallel'.

According to the package documentation, "If [parallel = ] TRUE and stepwise = FALSE, then the specification search is done in parallel.This can give a significant speedup on mutlicore machines."

If parallel = TRUE, it will automatically select how many 'cores' to use (for a laptop or desktop, it is often the number of cores * 2. For example, I have 4 cores and each core has 2 processors = 8 'cores').  If you want to manually set the number of cores, also use the argument num.cores.

I'd recommend checking out the [e-book](https://otexts.com/fpp2/) written by Hyndman all about the package.  It is like a time-series forecasting bible.

Comment: Your statement on `parallel` as regards `auto.arima()` is only true on paper but not in practice. Whenever I use `parallel = TRUE` and `stepwise = FALSE` it takes longer as I measure with `system.time()[[3]]`